# Using Viterbi Algorithm to find the most probable sequence

Tags: viterbi-algorithm

I have this problem, but I couldn't find any related literature.

Let's assume that I have this arrival process (the system can fit just one user):

With probability $P_a$ the next user is from class A and occupies the system for a time exponentially distributed with $\lambda = \lambda_a$. The same applies for users of class B (there are two classes)

Now, requests arrive according to an exponential distribution with $\lambda = \lambda_t$ and have a price associated $P_a$ and $P_b$ and $P_a > P_b$.

At each arrival I have to take the decision if I can accept the request or not, I may want to accept a user of class B but then if a class A user arrives before the current user has left the system, then I lose money.

My goal is to maximize the revenue by finding the best acceptance sequence over the future time window $T$. My idea is to use a Viterbi-alike algorithm and then select among the most probable sequences the one with the highest revenue.

Any pointer to similar problems in the literature?

Comment: There's a tricky issue of what you mean by "maximizing revenue" here. For example, fix a time $T$, then you can ask what strategy will give you the most money (expected value) at time $T$. Is this what you are interested in?

Also do we know the relationship between $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$? If $\lambda_a>\lambda_b$, then you would always accept customer $A$ when presented with one. If not, then it's more complicated.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in finding the best strategy (accepting or not the current user) based on the best sequence over the future time window $T$. There's no constraint on $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$